# Schedule a Task to run a PowerShell Script that uses Async Wait()

Tags: powershell, async-await, scheduled-tasks

I have an ASP MVC Controller Action that is an async method. I created a PowerShell script that works perfectly when run by itself, awaiting the results before completion.

Yet when I try to schedule it it will not wait. It executes and completes instantly without actually awaiting for the method to execute.

The scheduled Task used the Administrator account to run, so I just can't figure out what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In my case all I needed to do was give the full path of the PowerShell script as the argument.